# Jquery selector to remove css on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can not get hold of the right selector.
I tried all kind of stuff.

If I click on class navclick I want ONLY the next tr class to remove css class navdisplaynone.

```
$(".navclick").click(function(){
$(this).parent().next("tr").removeClass("navnone"); 
});
```

For your information : navdisplaynone is css class with rule :
display:none;

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="navtable">                  
<thead>
<tr id="pcatid1">
<th class="navclick">Software</th>
</tr>
<tr class="navdisplaynone" id="catid1">
<th class="navclick">Windows</th>
</tr>
<tr id="pcatid2">
<th class="navclick">Hardware</th>
</tr>
<tr class="navdisplaynone" id="catid2">
<th class="navclick">Mouse</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Code looks fine, you're not removing the right class tho - you remove `navone`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).parent().next("tr").removeClass("navdisplaynone");`

Comment: tymeJV was right, I did not select the right thing. Next should be :
.next(".navnone") right tymeJV ?

Comment: Your table has only table-headings (`<th>`), no table-data (`<td>`); have you removed content for the purpose of this code, or have you confused `<td>` and `<th>` elements?

Comment: I know, this is empty table. Just some sort of menu in table form.

Comment: @user3710844 THERE IS NOTHING SUCH AS `class="navnone"` IN YOUR DOM!! Why would you have your jquery refer it!?

Comment: Some guru edited my code. In my original i used class="navnone"

Comment: @user3710844: no, they didn't. Only you can edit your question within the (five minute) grace period without leaving an edit history. If you edit out another person's edit within the grace period, that leaves an edit history itself. You may have had a typo, but what you didn't get was a malicious, question-changing, edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style type="text/css">
.navdisplaynone{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body >
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="navtable">                  
<thead>
<tr id="pcatid1">
<th class="navclick">Software</th>
</tr>
<tr class="navdisplaynone" id="catid1">
<th class="navclick">Windows</th>
</tr>
<tr id="pcatid2">
<th class="navclick">Hardware</th>
</tr>
<tr class="navdisplaynone" id="catid2">
<th class="navclick">Mouse</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(".navclick").click(function(){
$(this).parent().next("tr").removeClass("navdisplaynone"); 
});
</script>

</html>
</head>
```

This work properly

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/gbuqond5/

Try this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $(".navclick").click(function(e){
  $(this).parent().next("tr").removeClass("navdisplaynone"); 
  });
});
```

Assuming your class was navdisplaynone 
Replace 'navdisplaynone' by 'navnone' in case that's the class.

**Note:** In case of a menu, you might want to toggle the class instead of remove.